# ¿Cuál es la forma adecuada en este caso?

Tags: clíticos

¿Cuál de estas oraciones es la correcta?

"Lois se vio forzado a pararse junto al escritorio en el que estaba el telégrafo por **los** que parecieron unos interminables minutos"

"Lois se vio forzado a pararse junto al escritorio en el que estaba el telégrafo por **lo** que parecieron unos interminables minutos"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considero que "lo que" es la opción correcta. "lo que" se refiere a la situación de tener que pararse junto al escritorio:

- ¿Qué es lo que parecieron unos interminables minutos? Pararse junto
  al escritorio...
- ¿Qué es los que parecieron unos interminables
  minutos? Esta preguntan no tendría sentido.